# How to count numbers which are defined in other table, also show zero counts

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the current situation:

Table1

| key | some_id | date | class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1.1.2000 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 1.1.2000 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 1.1.1999 | 3 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I'm counting the classes and providing the information through a view by using following select statement:

```
SELECT key, date, class, count(class) as cnt 
FROM table1 
GROUP BY key, date, class
```

The result would be:

| key | date | class | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.1.2000 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 1.1.1999 | 3 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

but now there is another table which includes all possible class-codes, e.g.

| parameter_key | class_code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| ... | ... |

For my view I'm only querying data for `parameter_key` 1. **And the view now needs to show all possible class_codes, also if the count would be 0.**

So my desired result table is:

| key | date | class | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.1.2000 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1.1.2000 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 1.1.2000 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 1.1.1999 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1.1.1999 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 1.1.1999 | 3 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

but I just can't get my head around how to do this. I've tried to add a `right join` like this but that does not change anything (probably because I join the class column and do an aggregate which won't be displayed if there is nothing to count?):

```
SELECT key, date, class, count(class) as cnt 
FROM table1 
RIGHT JOIN table2 on table1.class = table2.class and table2.parameter_key = 1 
GROUP BY key, date, class
```

Any idea on how to achieve the desired result table?

Comment: You want a cross join of key * class * date. Not sure what are the sources in the db. Possible options you can either select distinct values from the first table or have special tables enumerating the objects of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `PARTITION`ed join:

```sql
SELECT t2.parameter_key AS key,
       t1."DATE",
       t2.class_code AS class,
       count(t1.class) as cnt 
FROM   table2 t2
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 t1
       PARTITION BY (t1."DATE")
       ON (t1.class = t2.class_code AND t1.key = t2.parameter_key)
WHERE  t2.parameter_key = 1
GROUP BY
       t2.parameter_key,
       t1."DATE",
       t2.class_code
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (key, some_id, "DATE", class) AS
SELECT 1, 1, DATE '2000-01-01', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2, DATE '2000-01-01', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, DATE '1999-01-01', 3 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 (parameter_key, class_code) AS
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | KEY | DATE | CLASS | CNT |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1999-01-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 |
> | 1 | 1999-01-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 0 |
> | 1 | 1999-01-01 00:00:00 | 3 | 0 |
> | 1 | 2000-01-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 |
> | 1 | 2000-01-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 2 |
> | 1 | 2000-01-01 00:00:00 | 3 | 0 |

---

Or, depending on how you want to manage the join conditions:

```sql
SELECT t1.key,
       t1."DATE",
       t2.class_code AS class,
       count(t1.class) as cnt 
FROM   table2 t2
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 t1
       PARTITION BY (t1.key, t1."DATE")
       ON (t1.class = t2.class_code)
WHERE  t2.parameter_key = 1
GROUP BY
       t1.key,
       t1."DATE",
       t2.class_code
```

Which outputs:

> | KEY | DATE | CLASS | CNT |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 2000-01-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 |
> | 1 | 2000-01-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 2 |
> | 1 | 2000-01-01 00:00:00 | 3 | 0 |
> | 2 | 1999-01-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 |
> | 2 | 1999-01-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 0 |
> | 2 | 1999-01-01 00:00:00 | 3 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=464727f446646cf30f3f011ca6905bfe)*

Comment: First of all thank you very much!From the db<>fiddle I can see that it does exactly what I need.Unfortunately I was not able to apply this method to our actual DB because it takes ages to execute and I assume this is because of the PARTITION BY statement. Table1 actually includes >600 million rows while table2 holds around 200 class codes for a certain parameter. Of course I'm usually using the "some_id" in the WHERE clause to only query around, let's say, 1000-2000 rows from Table1.Is the PARTITION BY applied to the whole table first?Or is there another performance bottleneck here?

Comment: @spcial The bottleneck is probably the volume of data. 200 codes for 600 million rows would generate 120,000 million rows of output. Even for 1000 rows with 200 codes that would be 200,000 rows of output (which is not huge but if you are trying to display it in one go then it may still take a while). The `WHERE` filter should be applied before any `JOIN` conditions but you can check that by looking at the `EXPLAIN PLAN`.

Comment: That was it, I placed the WHERE right before any JOIN and it works like a charm! Thanks again!